# Can't print elements in a linked list after merging two arrays together into one list

Tags: data-structures, merge, linked-list, queue

I am working on an assignment for DS and Algo I am given two sorted integer lists or arrays then I have to merge them into one list. I decided to use two queues for each array by putting each element in the queue then do some comparisons and put them into a singly linked list. Now the problem I have faced is that it is only printing the first element over and over again in the first array. My goal is to put remove the elements in the queue and put them in a linked list from least to greatest.
Also the count in the while loop is used to stop the loop once it equals the length of both arrays - 1.

**MergeQueue.java**

```
    int[] A = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; // our first array A
    int[] B = {2, 3, 6, 8, 10}; // our second array B
    int length = A.length + B.length - 1; // get the length of both A and B
    //System.out.println(length);
    int count = 0; // this is a counter used to check that once count is equal to the length(A+B) then we break the loop
    int frontA, dequeueA;
    int frontB, dequeueB;

    // we can use a singly linked list to store elements of A and B
    SingleLinkedList S = new SingleLinkedList();
    QueueLinkList queueA = new QueueLinkList(); // our queue for A type integer
    QueueLinkList queueB = new QueueLinkList(); // our queue for B type integer

    // Add elements from A to the queue
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // so add element from A to the queue
        queueA.enqueue(A[i]);
    }

    // Add elements from B to the queue
    for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        // so add element from B to the queue
        queueB.enqueue(B[i]);
    }
    // now begins the conditions
    while(count != length) {
        // only return the element in the front not remove it
        frontA = queueA.front(); 
        frontB = queueB.front(); 

        if(frontA < frontB) {
            dequeueA = queueA.dequeue(); // remove the element and add it to the linked list
            // add dequeueA to list S
            S.add(dequeueA); // add the element to the singly linked list
            count++; // increment the counter
        }
        else if(frontB < frontA) {
            dequeueB = queueB.dequeue();
            // add dequeueB to list S
            S.add(dequeueB); // add the element to the singly linked list
            count++; // increment the counter
        }
        // if the elements are the same then remove from queue and add anyone.
        else if(frontA == frontB || frontB == frontA) {
            dequeueA = queueA.dequeue();
            dequeueB = queueB.dequeue();
            // add either dequeueA or B
            S.add(dequeueA); // add the element to the singly linked list
            count++; // increment the counter
        }
        // if queue A is empty and queue B is not then add remaining elements from B to S.
        else if(queueA.isEmpty() && !queueB.isEmpty()){
            // add remaining elements from B to the list
            dequeueA = queueA.dequeue(); 
            S.add(dequeueA);
            count++; // increment the counter
        }
        // if queue B is empty and queue A is not then add remaining elements from B to S.
        else if(queueB.isEmpty() && !queueA.isEmpty()) {
            // add remaining elements from B to the list
            dequeueB = queueB.dequeue();
            S.add(dequeueB);
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Our set S:");
    S.print(); // call the print method which displays every element in the singly linked list
```

Comment: The structure used above like SingleLinkedList and  QueueLinkList are these your custom implementation because in java for in-built link list list implementation we do LinkedList<String> S = new LinkedList<String>() and for Queue it is Queue<Integer> queueA = new LinkedList<>();. If it is your custom implementation please paste the code of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of code

```
else if(frontA == frontB || frontB == frontA) {
            dequeueA = queueA.dequeue();
            dequeueB = queueB.dequeue();
            // add either dequeueA or B
            S.add(dequeueA); // add the element to the singly linked list
            count++; // increment the counter
}
```

You need to increment count by 2 times since even though you are adding in link list once you are removing same element from both the queue and hence two elements are getting removed